# jqGrid string custom format like date format

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, spring-boot, jqgrid

I'm trying to print json data on web page with jqGrid, 
but there are some problems.

Here is my js script code.

```
$('#sometables').jqGrid({
    ...
    ...
    ...
    colNames: ['created_date'], 
    colModel: [ {name: 'created_date', align: 'center} ], 
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

`created_date` is json data(origin java String type).

So, I can see `created_date` on web page grid, like this : `20180912093510`, 
it means 2018/09/12 09:35:10.

**The problem is : How can I formatting string type in jqgrid?**

I want to see `2018/09/12 09:35:10`, not `20180912093510`.

**I tried first :**

```
{name: 'created_date', align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'Y/m/d H:i:s'}},
```

but it's result was : `NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN:NaN`

**I tried second :**

```
{name: 'created_date', align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'string', newformat: 'Y/m/d H:i:s'}},
```

but it's result was : `1970/01/01 00:00:00`

Can I convert string data to date-like data? Must make string-formatting function? If I can, please give some examples.

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? In any way, you need either modify input data on the client side or on the server side to provide any format, supported by predefined formatter `"date"` or to use custom formatter (which can optionally call predefined formatter `"date"` internally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, for example, custom formatter, which calls predefined date-formatter internally. The corresponding code could look like the following:

```
{
    name: "created_date",
    align: "center",
    sorttype: "integer",
    formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
        var fixedValue = cellValue.substr(0, 4) + "-" +
                cellValue.substr(4, 2) + "-" +
                cellValue.substr(6, 2) + "T" +
                cellValue.substr(8, 2) + ":" +
                cellValue.substr(10, 2) + ":" +
                cellValue.substr(12);
        return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", fixedValue, options, rowdata, action);
    },
    formatoptions: {
        srcformat: "ISO8601Long",
        newformat: "Y/m/d H:i:s"
    }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7pzy2x86/1/